# I get this error: dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: files list file for package `fonts-tlwg-kinnari' contains empty filename

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

When I try to install I get this error:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:  files list file for package `fonts-tlwg-kinnari' contains empty filename
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

And the installation is aborted.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a bug reported at launchpad.

The error shown will be either:

```
files list file for package '*' is missing final newline
```

Or:

```
files list file for package '*' contains an empty filename
```

Where * start is a random but steady "per install" package name.

**Solution:**

Donwload the .deb

```
sudo apt-get download fonts-tlwg-kinnari
```

Run this code

```
sudo dpkg -c /var/cache/apt/archives/fonts-tlwg-kinnari_1%3a0.5.1-3_all.deb  | awk '{if ($6 == "./") { print "/."; } \
else if (substr($6, length($6), 1) == "/") \
{print substr($6, 2, length($6) - 2); } \
else { print substr($6, 2, length($6) - 1);}}' > /var/lib/dpkg/info/fonts-tlwg-kinnari.list
```

You can read more at [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/108189)

Comment: This is the best solution to the problem. I've been lazy and I've used [the other solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/878446/63606) but it may cause `dpkg` to loose track of some files in system directories (à la Windows, just to be clear). The "funny" part is that my `linux-firmware.list` has been partly overwritten by [a Raspberry Pi file, `cpu-feature-overrides.h`](http://goo.gl/dC7Q9n). My system is not a RPi and it looks mostly ok (Smart is ok, dmesg is not crimson-red, etc). I still have to perform a `memtest` run, but this episode should just be the weird outcome of a sudden power loss...

Comment: This is also the one solution that helped me. Please note that it may be due to a filesystem corruption (raspberry pi in my case). The .list file contained some file entries but then some stuff that looked like log output. The reported file length was exactly the same for both files, unfortunately I deleted the corrupt .list file before checking again.

Answer (score 11):

Another option from Adrian's answer above is this:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/fonts-tlwg-kinnari.list
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall fonts-tlwg-kinnari
```

Basically, this error means something got corrupted on your filesystem. It's a bad sign, and these list files are needed for the package manager to figure out what is and isn't safe to upgrade.

This regeneration of the list file is the best option, but it's not 100% safe.

Either way, keep in mind that something went wrong with your drive, and watch out for more errors.

Comment: Worked very well for me, and is a lot simpler than the other option.

Answer (score 1):

Adrian Cid Almaguer's answer is the only thing that worked for me, the general idea being "recreate the missing file from the .deb package".

A note though: check first in `/var/cache/apt/archives/` and `/var/lib/dpkg/info` to see if the .deb file already exists. If so, just use that instead of doing the `sudo apt-get download`.

Also, `sudo dpkg ... | awk ... | sudo tee /var/lib/dpkg/info/example.list` is likely to work better for most people; the `sudo tee` combination overcoming the permissions problem `>` redirection encounters.

Answer (score 1):

I finally had some time to fix this on my own. For future reference

I moved all the linux* files to somewhere else. ex: ~/ (home) sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux* ./

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

That fixed it

Comment: this did not solve the issue for me