# Updating, installation dpkg problem in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I am just a user of ubuntu for the past 10 years. Do not know inner working. I am on Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit. Settings doesn't open. 
Software updater finally throws up this message -

"The installation or removal of a software package failed"

And whenever I try to install  updates through terminal or install any software I get finally this -

dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'libsmbclient:i386' contains empty filename
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

What could be the problem? Any hope of getting back to normal?

Comment: It is likely that the package list for `libsmbclient` has become corrupted. I think @imperial-lord is on the right track, even though he has just copied and pasted things relating to a different package which will NOT work for this one. Try to follow his workflow but substitute `libsmbclient` whenever he says `fonts-tlwg-kinnari`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I get this error: dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: files list file for package \`fonts-tlwg-kinnari' contains empty filename](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648736/i-get-this-error-dpkg-unrecoverable-fatal-error-aborting-files-list-file-for)

Answer (score 1):

Please list the contents of your apt cache by using:

`ls -l /var/cache/apt/archives/`

This list should contain the list of packages in the cache, including the complete name of the package causing issues. Look for something that contains `libsmbclient`. Copy the complete file name, including the `.deb` extension at the end.

Confirm that the file is corrupted by using this formula, with your actual file name:

`dpkg --contents /var/cache/apt/archive/<complete name of the libsmbclient file here>.deb`

An uncorrupted file will show a listing of directories and files. Anything else means that the file is corrupted. Then you can download the needed file:

`sudo apt-get --reinstall --download-only libsmbclient`

And carry out the repair using this command (copy as is but substitute `full-name-of-your-package.deb` with the actual name of your `.deb` file in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`:

```
sudo dpkg -c /var/cache/apt/archives/full-name-of-your-package.deb  | awk '{if ($6 == "./") { print "/."; } \
else if (substr($6, length($6), 1) == "/") \
{print substr($6, 2, length($6) - 2); } \
else { print substr($6, 2, length($6) - 1);}}' > /var/lib/dpkg/info/libsmbclient.list
```

For more info on how and why this happens, you can look at the original [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/108189) bug report or [another example of this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648736/i-get-this-error-dpkg-unrecoverable-fatal-error-aborting-files-list-file-for/878446#878446) here in AskUbuntu, but affecting a different package name.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the link [I get this error: dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: files list file for package `fonts-tlwg-kinnari' contains empty filename](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648736/i-get-this-error-dpkg-unrecoverable-fatal-error-aborting-files-list-file-for)

This is the answer, just for slow connections:
This is a bug reported at launchpad.

The error shown will be either:

files list file for package '*' is missing final newline
Or:

files list file for package '*' contains an empty filename
Where * start is a random but steady "per install" package name.

Solution:

Donwload the .deb

sudo apt-get download fonts-tlwg-kinnari
Run this code

sudo dpkg -c /var/cache/apt/archives/fonts-tlwg-kinnari_1%3a0.5.1-3_all.deb  | awk '{if ($6 == "./") { print "/."; } \
else if (substr($6, length($6), 1) == "/") \
{print substr($6, 2, length($6) - 2); } \
else { print substr($6, 2, length($6) - 1);}}' > /var/lib/dpkg/info/fonts-tlwg-kinnari.list 
You can read more at launchpad

Comment: Why are you suggesting actions for a completely unrelated software package? The OP's problems are with `libsmbclient:i386`.

Comment: If you're copy-pasting from another solution, please take the time to adapt to the actual question being answered and substitute `fonts-tlwg-kinnari` with the package name in the original question: `libsmbclient`.