# dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, dpkg

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.3

I am getting this error when running **sudo apt full-upgrade**

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  brave-browser command-not-found ghostscript ghostscript-x google-chrome-stable libgs9 libgs9-common liblightdm-gobject-1-0 libnss-systemd libpam-systemd libsystemd0
  libsystemd0:i386 libudev1 libudev1:i386 lightdm linux-firmware linux-libc-dev openssh-client python3-commandnotfound systemd systemd-sysv systemd-timesyncd
  ubuntu-drivers-common udev
24 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/308 MB of archives.
After this operation, 2,211 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-tlwg-kinnari' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'linux-headers-5.11.0-43-generic' contains empty filename
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your Ubuntu version. And please format your error correctly as a code block (put ``` before and after it, on a separate line from the error itself).

Comment: similar question https://askubuntu.com/q/648736/1186757

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I get this error: dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: files list file for package \`fonts-tlwg-kinnari' contains empty filename](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648736/i-get-this-error-dpkg-unrecoverable-fatal-error-aborting-files-list-file-for)